# Center text and input field? asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need help to center align a login form, the labels and input fields.As it stands the login is aligned left which makes it look bad and out of place. Can someone please help my code can be seen below. It is in asp.net C#

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"    Inherits="ARAF_Sales_Order_Approval.Default" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">.auto-style5 {
    width: 131px;
    }
    </style>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"   runat="server">
<tr>
    <td>
<table>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
            Agent Name
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style5">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_AgentName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style5">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style5">

            <asp:Button ID="Button_Login" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Login_Click" Text="Login" />

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style5">
            <asp:Label ID="Label_LoginStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the table inside a div. Then give a style to this div like:

> max-width: 330px;
>       padding: 15px;
>       margin: 0 auto;

That's it. You can change the pixels as you want.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help.. @Ahmet Onur